# How to display gif or mp4 for both GTK and WPF using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.forms, gtk

it's a little extraordinary, but I use Xamarin Forms for WPF and GTK. Maybe somebody knows any common solution for these platforms to display gif or (if it's easier) MP4 format file.
There are a lot of solutions even on SO, but almost all of them connected with Android/IOS/UWP

Answer (score 0):

The best opt for animation is Lottie, maybe it'll fit for u, but you need to create json gifs with Adobe AE or use animations from this [site](https://lottiefiles.com/featured)

[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie/)

[Installation Guide](https://xamarinhelp.com/lottie-animations-xamarin-forms/)